# UI component Filter with category collection Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, collection, uicomponent

I am implementing Grid for categories collection using UI component.

I have used the following code

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_index_index.xml**

```
 <body>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="vendor_manage_listing"/>
     </referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_manage_listing.xml**

```
<columns name="seoreport_category_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="value">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="is_active">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Status</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Category Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
   </columns>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Category extends  AbstractDb
{

  protected function _construct()
   {
      /* Main Table Name */
     $this->_init('catalog_category_entity','entity_id');
   }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Collection.php**

```
<?php

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Category', 
    'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category');
   }
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
     return $this;
   }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Grid/Collection.php**

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection as EntityCollection;

class Collection extends EntityCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{

   protected $aggregations;
   protected $request; 
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $connection,
        $resource
        $this->request = $request;
    );
    $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
    $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
    $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
    $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
   }

/**
 * @return AggregationInterface
 */
 public function getAggregations()
  {
    return $this->aggregations;
  }
  public function setItems(array $items = null)
  {
    return $this;
  }
 protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
 {
    $filters = $this->request->getParam('filters');
    if (isset($filters['is_active'])) {
        $is_active = $filters['is_active'];
        if ($is_active == 0) {
            $this->getSelect()->orWhere("main_table.is_active = 1");
        }
    }

    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
  }
}
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Status.php**

```
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Status implements ArrayInterface
{
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
      $result = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptions() as $value => $label) {
           $result[] = [
             'value' => $value,
             'label' => $label,
           ];
      }

       return $result;
   }

   public function getOptions()
   {
       return [
          '1' => __('All Categories'),
          '0' => __('Visible Categories')
       ];
   }
}
```

If the first option selected I need to load all categories if the second option is selected I need to show only categories which are enabled.

> I am looking for below 2 solutions.
>
> 1.Filter should work once applied
>
> 2.I have to show Category Status only in Filter not in Column.

How can we implement above functionality. Someone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: For ui grid filter?

Comment: Have you `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Grid\Collection` file?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh, Yes I have that file, updated in my question

Comment: I am getting is_active unknown column error @DhadukMitesh

Comment: Error happens when running php bin/magento s:d:c [24-Oct-2020 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AbstractCollection' not found in Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Collection.php:3. To fix this error add  use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection; TO Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Collection.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this into  your listing xml file

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**vendor_manage_listing.xml**

```
<container name="listing_top">
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_manage_listing.vendor_manage_listing.seoreport_category_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_manage_listing.vendor_manage_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_manage_listing.vendor_manage_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">vendor_manage_listing.vendor_manage_listing.seoreport_category_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterSelect name="is_active">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Status</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_active</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Status</item>
                        <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
</container>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source**

**Status.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Status implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options['0'] = __('Visible Categories');
        $options['1'] = __('All Categories');
        return $options;
    }
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

> before filter

[image]

> after filter 
>   [image]

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: hi @Msquare, can i remove the column is_active code from the listing file?

Comment: I tried this but filter not working after Apply filter.

Comment: above code is ruuning , and you can remove is_active column

Comment: yes I removed is_active column from listing file, now the filter showing with 3 options, once select any option and apply filter, its not working, getting unknown column is_active error

Comment: you doing something wrong it's works see my screen shot

Comment: yes may be, Possible to update complete module?

Comment: yes i will send you both file. give me your email id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104835/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-msquare).

Comment: @jafarpinjar have you done ?

Comment: No, I am stuck with that issue, column not found

Comment: Don't worry I will help you send me your module zip. I will check and solve and send back to you

Comment: Sure, I will send you in 1hr, if u can pls help help me on the display out of stock issue, which i enabled yesterday.that's very important for me now

Comment: hi @Msquare, sent you complete module

Comment: @jafarpinjar according your reqirement i have done and send Module zip to you. so now it's wroks so please accept answer

Comment: hi @Msqure, Thanks for sharing, but I am modifying the code for after saving category in admin, sure will accept it, after my code change.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code in `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/seoreport_category_listing.xml` file in the `filters` tab.

```
<filterSelect name="value">
    <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">X247commerce\Seoreports\Model\Config\Source\Status</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
            <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</item>
            </item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">value</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Status</item>
            <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string"></item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filterSelect>
```

And remove the `is_active` column.

Add below function in `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection.php` file.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $catalog_category_entity_int = $this->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['category_entity_int' => $catalog_category_entity_int],
        'main_table.entity_id = category_entity_int.entity_id',
        [
            'main_table.entity_id',
            'category_entity_int.value',
        ]
    );
}
```

Add below function in `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Grid\Collection.php` file.

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $filters = $this->request->getParam('filters');
    if (isset($filters['value'])) {
        $is_active = $filters['value'];
        if ($is_active == 0) {
            $this->getSelect()->orWhere("category_entity_int.value is not null");
        }
        if ($is_active == 1) {
            $this->getSelect()->orWhere("category_entity_int.value = 1");
        }
    }

    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

And then clear cache and check it.

Comment: hi @Dhaduk, I do not have any collection file inside Grid directory, can you please update me full code of that file

Comment: I did research and updated that file, but still filter is not working, pls check once

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: hi @Dhaduk, getting this error in log, Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_active' in 'where clause'

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: yes, but no change, error after applying filter

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104834/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-jafar-pinjar).