# magento 2 Admin Change grid data based on the selected options via ajax

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have an admin form inside which I have added a dropdown and one grid  with UI component

I want to change the grid data or need to apply filers to grid collection based on the selected value inside the dropdown

Ex. if I select option 1 then the grid will show data depending on that option and if I select option 2 then data is based on that value

how can I do this ?
Your help is appreciated

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305126/82670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved This by myself,

Please check the below article by me for a solution

https://smitakagwade.medium.com/magento-2-admin-form-ui-component-change-grid-data-based-on-the-selected-options-via-ajax-641f94ae53a5

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this for Filter: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-custom-filter-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-2.html

Refer to this for dropdown: https://www.hungersoft.com/info/add-select-component-magento2-ui-component-admin-grid

Happy coding